# Working with basic jQuery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

As the title says, I'm trying to add a simple slider on an `.html` page.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Slider
  $("#slider-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 23,
    values: [0, 23],
    step: 1,
    slide: slideTime
  });
});

function slideTime(event, ui) {
  var val0 = $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0),
    val1 = $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1);
  var text = "";
  if (val0 < 12)
    text += val0 + "AM - ";
  else
    text += val0 + "PM - ";
  console.log(val0);
  console.log(val1);
  if (val1 < 12)
    text += val1 + "AM";
  else
    text += val1 + "PM";
  $("#time").text(text);
}
```

The problem that I'm facing is that the range should be from 0 to 23. However, when I use the slider, the lower bound goes from 1, to 0, to 1 again... As the upper bound seems to go from 22 to 23 to 22 again...

I'm not sure why this happens.

Here can be found an minimal example:

https://jsfiddle.net/7wft437c/

Comment: Well.  Its not just that.  Drop the slider somewhere along the line.  Now pick it up and go back and forth between -1 and +1 from where it started.  Sometimes you'll go +1 and the value will change -1 or vice versa.

Comment: Instead of `slide:slideTime` try to use `stop:slideTime` or `change:..` You call the function as you slide, but the value hasn't changed until you release the slider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
var val0 = $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0),
val1 = $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1);
```

Get the values in this way

```
var val0 = ui.values[0],
val1 = ui.values[1];
```

[This is the Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7wft437c/8/)

Comment: I was poking around with things and came to this same answer (starting with the jQuery UI example and working forward).  I don't know what it is about `.slider("values", 0)` that causes it to retrieve the wrong value, but `ui.values[0]` is the way to go.  As soon as I made that change I got the strange behavior.

Comment: @Draco18s Probably the .slider("values",0) don't have still the correct value in the slide event. The Tony solution work because at the stop event the values are just set, but you don't have the correct value during the slide.

Comment: That makes sense.  I'd still go this route personally, no need to jQuery-select the element when its handed to you on a platter with the event method.

Comment: But with @TonyHinkle solution, if I call slideTime(); after the slider is initialized I get an error when trying to access `ui.values[x]`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change `slide: slideTime` to `stop: slideTime`.

`slide` gets the state before before the position changes, and your code is set up to evaluate where the slider is when the slide is done.

You can also call `slideTime()` after the slider is initialized so that it will label it before the user touches it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Slider
  $("#slider-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 23,
    values: [0, 23],
    step: 1,
    stop: slideTime
  });
  slideTime();
});
```

Comment: But this is a workaround, you change the event, in the stop event the values are set. The JQuery doc use the ui object for retrive the vlaues in the specific events.

Comment: @Baro I agree with you, docs are indeed saying to use `slide` also with a range value. I think the slider function retrieves it's new values in the next browser tic or something.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the update function is firing as soon as its moved, before it reaches its new value.

try using `change`.

or if you want to keep it updating as you are sliding, use a timeout:-

```
function slideTime(event, ui) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var val0 = $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0),
      val1 = $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1);
    var text = "";
    if (val0 < 12)
      text += val0 + "AM - ";
    else
      text += val0 + "PM - ";
    console.log(val0);
    console.log(val1);
    if (val1 < 12)
      text += val1 + "AM";
    else
      text += val1 + "PM";
    $("#time").text(text);
  }, 100);
}
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/7wft437c/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Check this working sample here where you can define a separate slide function based on your required slider behaviour : [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jairajdesai/7wft437c/21/)

```js
  $("#slider-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 1440,
    step: 15,
    values: [0, 1440],
    slide: function(e, ui) {
      var hours1 = Math.floor(ui.values[0] / 60);
      var minutes1 = ui.values[0] - (hours1 * 60);
      $('.slider-time').html(hours1 * 100 + minutes1 * 1);
      if (hours1.length == 1) hours1 = '0' + hours1;
      if (minutes1.length == 1) minutes1 = '0' + minutes1;
      if (minutes1 == 0) minutes1 = '00';
      if (hours1 >= 12) {
        if (hours1 == 12) {
          hours1 = hours1;
          minutes1 = minutes1 + " PM";
        } else {
          hours1 = hours1 - 12;
          minutes1 = minutes1 + " PM";
        }
      } else {
        hours1 = hours1;
        minutes1 = minutes1 + " AM";
      }
      if (hours1 == 0) {
        hours1 = 12;
        minutes1 = minutes1;
      }
      var hours2 = Math.floor(ui.values[1] / 60);
      var minutes2 = ui.values[1] - (hours2 * 60);
      $('.slider-time2').html(hours2 * 100 + minutes2 * 1);
      if (hours2.length == 1) hours2 = '0' + hours2;
      if (minutes2.length == 1) minutes2 = '0' + minutes2;
      if (minutes2 == 0) minutes2 = '00';
      if (hours2 >= 12) {
        if (hours2 == 12) {
          hours2 = hours2;
          minutes2 = minutes2 + " PM";
        } else if (hours2 == 24) {
          hours2 = 11;
          minutes2 = "59 PM";
        } else {
          hours2 = hours2 - 12;
          minutes2 = minutes2 + " PM";
        }
      } else {
        hours2 = hours2;
        minutes2 = minutes2 + " AM";
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="time-range">
  <p style='background-color: #be9f57;color:#000;' class='plot-options-font'>Time Range: <span class="slider-time">0000</span> - <span class="slider-time2">2400</span>
  </p>
  <div class="sliders_step1">
    <div id="slider-range"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And additionally, you can add the PM and AM at the end of the time that is displayed in the spans or the step based on your requirements.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you adding the values configuration option. Try removing it:

```
 values: [0, 23],
```

Answer (score 0):

try this solution:

```
function slideTime(event, ui) {
val0 = ui.values[0];
val1 = ui.values[1];

  var text = "";
  if (val0 < 12)
    text += val0 + "AM - ";
  else
    text += val0 + "PM - ";

  if (val1 < 12)
    text += val1 + "AM";
  else
    text += val1 + "PM";
  $("#time").text(text);
}
```